# I have installed the flutter and android studio but still getting the error zsh: command not found: flutter

Tags: flutter

I have installed the flutter and android studio but still getting the error

**tushar@racs-MacBook-Pro ~ % flutter doctor
zsh: command not found: flutter**

i was trying to update the envirnmental variable on my macbook by using the "nano ~/.zshrc" command but after adding the same I am not able to run any flutter command on terminal

please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
First, open the terminal on your mac.

Next, use the command

 cat .bash_profile
and copy the content.

Then type this command into the terminal:

nano $ HOME / .zshrc
and paste the content just copied above into. Save then type

source $ HOME / .zshrc
to refresh this file. Next type

echo $ PATH
to see if the content has been updated. If successful type

flutter --version
```